# Overheads of Win7 in VirtualBox on Win10

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I just bought a new Intel 10th Gen NUC10i7FNH, with the intention of installing Win7 on it.

Yes, I know Win7 is out of support, and Win10 is likely to be the future indefinitely now, but I like being in the Win7 space and I want to keep a working example of it handy for the long term.

I have since found there are several reasons why this is unlikely to work.

After disabling Secure Boot and UEFI Boot, I can run Win7 setup, but it gets stuck at the first screen, because without USB3 drivers it cannot detect the keyboard.

I have tried splicing USB3 drivers into the setup ISO (Intel provides instructions for this and Gigabyte has a utility) but this doesn't work either, and nor does adding USB2 ports from the internal header pins. These ports work (for example when navigating setup) but are still not detected by Win7 setup.

I believe this is because the latest USB3 xHCI driver for Win7 does not support the 10th gen chipset, and there is unlikely to be one released that does.

So it's looking hopeless. Belated research indicates that the 6th Gen NUCs are the last to officially support Win7 but with lots of disclaimers about limited support for the advanced features of the NUC.

It seems retrograde to go back to an older NUC model like this, especially if Win7 is still only going to get limited access to its processing power.

So then I started thinking about bowing to the inevitable and installing Win10, but running Win7 as a VirtualBox VM, and spending most of my time in there. Seems ideal, I get the environment I want, and can even transfer it to future PCs indefinitely.

So I'm wondering, how would Win7 performance as a VM on Win10 compare to installing Win7 directly on the metal?

It strikes me that if Win10 can take full advantage of the 10th gen NUC chipset, and Win7 can't (even if installation was possible) then there may actually be an advantage in having a Win10 host to provide surrogate access to these hardware services.

Are there any drawbacks I should be aware of in taking this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very new computers are unlikely to run Windows 7. Manufacturers are designing them not to support Windows 7.  So that is what you are seeing above.

Now to your question:  I have a ThinkPad X1 with fast NVMe SSD and lots of CPU and memory. It runs Windows 10 Pro 64-bit.

On this machine I have a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit guest with Office, Adobe and other tools. It runs fine. I can (and regularly do) run Kali and Ubuntu at the same time. All the machines are fast, so I do not see any major drawbacks.

I use VMware Workstation V15.5 and the host provides hardware to the guests via VMware.  VMware (in my experience and from what I read) is better for this than Virtual Box.

All in all a very good solution to your situation.

Comment: Thanks John, that's reassuring.  I've also just discovered Hyper-V.  Any thoughts on Hyper-V vs VMware vs VirtualBox?  As part of Windows, it seems the obvious choice to start playing with, unless the others have a significant advantage.

Comment: Hyper-V is fine as well. Make sure Hyper-V runs all the guests you might wish. It certainly runs Windows 7. Best of luck in your project. I am very happy with my setup.